# Taylor-series of ln(x)

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Is it possible to compute the Taylor-series of $\ln(x)$ for $x = 0$. I get $f\prime(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and by plugging $0$ , it is undefined form.

Comment: About $x=0$ the function $\ln x$ is not differentiable.

Comment: It is also not defined.

Comment: So the question : calculate Limit using Taylor-series $\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$ is wrong? where $\lim{x \to 0}$

Comment: That limit doesn't exist - $|ln(x)|$ tends to infinty, as does $1/x$, so the limit is not defined.

Comment: The limit does exist -- it is $+\infty$. (The limit has to be as $x\to 0^+$, since $\ln$ is not defined for negative numbers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible since

$$x\mapsto \ln(x)$$

is not defined at $x=0$.

Though you can develop $\ln(x)$ in terms of $x-1$, and then divide by $x$ to get the development of $\ln(x)/x$ that you said you wanted in the comments.

Comment: In other words, it is $ln(1+x)$ which is analytic in the vicinity of $0$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, exactly.